# Software for Soft Body Dynamics

Tags: simulation

I am searching for some software to simulate the behaviour of soft bodies like cheese in an quantitive way. For example I want to know the forces in the body during the simulation. 
I thought of programming one by myself but this would probably take way too long. And I'm confused about all the programs I found on google.

So does anyone know some software to simulate things like cheese?